# OWL API merging individuals

Tags: merge, owl, owl-api

I need to merge two individuals with OWL API (I mean, given two individuals A, B, adding all axioms and annotation involving B in A). Let axiomsSet be the set of axioms involving B. Is there any simple way to replace B with A in each axiom in axiomsSet?
Thank you.

Comment: [`OWLEntityRenamer`](https://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_5/org/semanticweb/owlapi/util/OWLEntityRenamer.html) would be the only built-in way I'm aware of. Just wrap the axioms in an `OWLOntology` object, rename the IRI, and take the modified axioms

Comment: Ok, what if i use OWLEntityRenamer with the individual? If an individual with the same IRI exists, does it merge axioms and assertions?

Comment: what means merge? it just replaces IRIs in axioms. if you have a property assertion axiom `p(a, b)` and replace `a` by `c` then you have an axiom `p(c, b)`

Comment: Axioms for an entity are not linked to each other in any way. Renaming an entity in an axiom means removing the old axiom and adding a new one; this is indistinguishable from 'merging axioms and assertions on the new entity', because that sentence simply means 'the new axioms use an entity with the same IRI as another entity mentioned in the ontology'. In short, yes, OWLEntityRenamer does what's required here.

Comment: That is what I need, thank you.